# Django: Upload file from Admin site

Tags: django, file, django-admin

Is there any way to upload a file from the admin site. I have a class Contract and I'd like to upload a file where the contract is scanned.

Comment: It's my first Django project and I don't know how to upload a file. I've had a look to some books (The definitive guide to Django, The Django book, etc.) but I haven't found anything so I'd like to find a clue about how to begin. I've seen there's a module (FileSystemStorage) which it could be useful but I still need more info or an example in order to know how it works. Sorry, for not being more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume this is your model:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
  scanned_image = models.FileField(upload_to='scanned_images/')
```

and you just need to register your model to admin. create admin.py in your app folder and put this in it:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Contract

admin.site.register(Contract)
```

and in admin now, if you `add new contact`, you will see an image upload field for `scanned_image` field. if you upload it, the uploaded file will land into `media/scanned_images` folder.

hope, this helps

Answer (score 1):

It should works out of the box. Just add [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) into your model and specify [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) settings

If you need to go deeper, start with django docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/